# Print subprocess.call result

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to return the temperature of my drive in a single string with "Temp: " as a prefix. To get there I run a simple script for concatenating a string with the output of a command.

```
import subprocess

command = "sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda | egrep Temperature_Celsius | awk '{print $10}'"

print "Temp " + str(subprocess.call(command, shell=True))
```

Result:

```
29
Temp 0
```

When I delete the 'print' line, the '29' also does not show. So when I use a print statement, the script returns the '29' for some reason (?!) and then returns 0 out of the blue while the 29 is actually the right value.

I wish I would get this:

```
Temp: 29
```

I have tried to use os.system and that gives the same results. 
I have also tried to add the command directly into the "command = str(subprocess.call(" but it gave the same results.
I've read the os.system info pages and the subprocess.call info pages, I did not find a solution. Then I Googled for the AWK command, maybe it creates some crazy output but I can't find anything useful.

*Python 2.7 on Linux 3.8.0-34-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 18:00:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` returns the [process exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) (where `0` means success). If you wanted the process output, use [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead:

```
print "Temp " + subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: bah you have lightning fingers :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley I saw Martijn vacationing in bahamas. This is his bot answering while he is away.